# C# Released program , .exe and dll, when hit start, works on my computer but not others

Tags: c#, dll, crash

So basically I coded something and when I press start, it uses content from dlls etc..
And when I do it everything works fine I got all the `.dll`s in the same folder as the `.exe`, 
but on someone else's computer it just wont work, it crashes, boom.

Even though he has everything 100% like me

I don't know what to do to find what causes this, any way to know?

```
private void nsButtonAutoStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        secondThread = new Thread( () => Start(dsflfsdl, sgdsgd, sggdsg, etc));

        secondThread.Start();          
    }
```

What it does is :

```
if (!Directory.Exists(user))
                        Directory.CreateDirectory(user);
```

than create more folders with a given name etc.. well I won't describe everything, just need to know how to spot what's wrong.

Comment: well we won't tell you the answer until you describe more!

Comment: `Start(dsflfsdl, sgdsgd, sggdsg, etc)` Do you really think that the way to ask a question is to shut your eyes and press keys at random?

Answer (score 0):

There are several exceptions that can be thrown from this, so I'll go over causes of the most likely culprits...

- Framework: this can be the case when the .NET Framework is not installed, or the right version isn't installed. Note that the `System.___` Dlls are ususally included in the GAC, but can sometimes be missing. Install a GAC Browser tool and make sure everything you reference in your project is not only installed, but also show up properly in the GAC.
- Permissions: It's possible that since the program is rexognized as coming from somewhere else and lacks publisher signing, it doesn't have filesystem permissions, and is thus crashing for even trying to look at files. This can be resolved by trying to have the other computer `Run as Administrator` in Windows. This can also cause `DLL Not Found` exceptions because of being unable to reach into the running directory for required Dlls.

**How to find the exception**: If the client sees a "program has stopped working" window, there'll often be the option to see "more details," in which one of the lines of "More Data X" will be the actual exception type.

- Missing Method Exception: this can happen if it can't find a method. This can happen if you're "providing" DLLs that are also present on the GAC (say, System or mscorlib). Becuase Assembly Resolution checks the GAC first, it will use the GAC version if it's present, *even if you've provided a copy*. This can cause issues if you don't specify the requirement of a specific version, becuase it could hook into a .NET 4.0 assembly where it should be grabbing a 4.5 one. Make sure the right version of .NET is installed, and try making your project `Require Sepcific Version: True` for all references

Comment: I found the error , it says :
System.MissingMethodException: Method not found:
But why would it find it on my computer and not on his if i provide the .dll?

Comment: That's also a number of answers, so I'll throw a few more steps onto my answer

Answer (score -1):

I found the problem, basically it was the .dll that they had , it was the good one but it lacked some data in it, it was 300 kb instead of 454 kb

Comment: If you find the answer mark this as the answer of the question so that other people may have this problem have the answer.